# InvalidAMIID with Amazon AWS EC2 API

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm querying the AWS API and trying to launch an instance with the AMI ID that is located in us-west-1a. This is failing with an error of InvalidAMIID. Using the same API keys I'm able to launch an AMI in us-east-1b. Has anyone have experience with this? I'm positive I'm doing something wrong. Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to narrow this down to one of two things:

- The AWS REST API requires both region and availability zone to be specified. It isn't possible to just specify the availability zone.

  OR
- The above problem lies actually in the 'aws' ruby gem

Comment: There are different API endpoints for each region, so you always need to indicate your region if it is not the default (us-east-1).  It is possible that some API tools will extract the region if you specify an availability zone, but in your specific case it sounds like that tool does not do so.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I'm pretty sure I saw a hard-coded EC2 URI which obviously wasn't inferring the region.

Answer (score 0):

The AMI's are different from region to region -- you can't call an AMI in us-east-* in us-west-*.  If this is a custom AMI, you'll need to move it over to the new region, or just find the corresponding AMI if it's a public AMI.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. They're in the specified region in my API call. I only try to launch an instance for us-west-1a with an AMI in that region and us-east-1b with an AMI in that region.

Comment: Can you launch it via the console?

Comment: Hrms.  Then you might need to open a support ticket -- if you can open it via the EC2 console, but can't via the API, that's a (strange) issue.

Comment: Yeh. I've decided to give it a miss anyway since Amazon requires paid support. I've now switched to recreating the entire instance from us-east-1b.